# using $.ajax in kendoui datasource of Grid

Tags: jquery, ajax, kendo-ui, grid

I'm trying to use jquery ajax call for datasource update in my kendoui Grid.
The sample of code (getting from docs):

```js
update: function(options) {
      // make JSONP request to http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products/update
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: AjaxSave,
        dataType: "json", // "jsonp" is required for cross-domain requests; use "json" for same-domain requests
        success: function(result) {
          options.success(result);
        },
        error: function(result) {
          options.error(result);
        }
      });
    }
```

But I'm getting the following error after Update clicking:

```
Error: Only json dataType can be used for update operation.     

...o](n,e[o]):n[o]=e[o]}else{if("json"!==l)throw Error("Only json
dataType can be u...
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically, it appears correct. I've known this to occur at one point when there was incompatibility between the installed jQuery version and the Kendo version used.

You may want to cross check your jQuery/Kendo version compatibility, and update/rollback if necessary.

Comment: I'm take kendo.all.min.js and jquery.min.js from newest trial kendoui and there are no changes..